# Prisma: How would I link multiple columns to the same data type

Tags: postgresql, next.js, foreign-keys, relationship, prisma

New to relational databases, and am using Prisma with Postgres, and Nextjs for a project. I am sending out emails to customers, and want to store these emails, but don't fully understand how the relationships work, to get it fully working.

I have email recipients that relate to a customer. Here there is a name and email address.

```
model email_recipient {
  id            String   @id(map: "pk_email_recipient") @db.Uuid
  name          String   @db.VarChar(255)
  email_address String   @db.VarChar(255)
  customer_id   String   @unique @db.Uuid
  customer      customer @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id])
}
```

And I have an email model, that has `to`, `cc`, and `bcc` columns, that could be multiple email recipients. The recipient could technically exist in all three.

```
model email {
  id                 String    @id(map: "pk_email") @db.Uuid
  body               String?   @db.Text
  created_date       DateTime? @db.Timestamp(6)
  last_modified_date DateTime? @db.Timestamp(6)
  to                 email_recipient[]
  cc                 email_recipient[]
  bcc                email_recipient[]
}
```

Prisma attempts to generate relationships for me, but I doesn't fully work as it adds the same named field 3 times, like so.

```
model email_recipient {
  id            String   @id(map: "pk_email_recipient") @db.Uuid
  name          String   @db.VarChar(255)
  email_address String   @db.VarChar(255)
  customer_id   String   @unique @db.Uuid
  customer      customer @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id])
  user          user[]
  email         email?   @relation(fields: [emailId], references: [id])
  emailId       String?  @db.Uuid
  email         email?   @relation(fields: [emailId], references: [id])
  emailId       String?  @db.Uuid
  email         email?   @relation(fields: [emailId], references: [id])
  emailId       String?  @db.Uuid
  // Clearly an issue here, but not prismas fault, its just trying its best.
}
```

I have attempted to add an intermediary table in between with a recipient type enum, but could not get that to work. I think it is the right solution, but this is where my understanding of relationships break down.